# Grouping the same songs on Rhythmbox and playing only the highest quality version

Tags: rhythmbox

Most of my music collection is recorded from CDs or vinyl records in FLAC. However, since my car stereo doesn't support this format, I'm kind of forced to keep both a FLAC file and an MP3 file. Besides, some of my older digital music purchases only came in MP3s.

I was wondering if there's any way to hide these duplicates in Rhythmbox and have it only play the FLAC version, when it's available.